# Oracle Query to Get Distinct Values of First Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario like below and i want to know the oracle query to get the distinct values of first table `USER` column like

```
EXPECTED RESULT

ID   |  USER                       
11   |  user3                     
12   |  user4 




CURRENT TABLES

TABLE A                TABLE B  

ID   |  USER           ID   |  USER            
11   |  user1          11   |  user1           
11   |  user2          11   |  user2          
11   |  user3          12   |  user5
12   |  user4
12   |  user5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way is to use `minus`:

```
select id, user
from a
minus
select id, user
from b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach:

```
select * from tableA where user not in (select distinct(user) from tableB)
```